# A scalable bus with multiple Camel instances

Tags: apache-camel, soa, apache-servicemix

My idea is to use camel to decouple modules. In order to support scalability and failover, I am wondering if the following architecture is adviced?

I have two applications with Camel embedded AppCamel1 and AppCamel2. Then I have standalone camel nodes Camel1 and Camel2.

AppCamel1 would have a route with fail-over/load balancing to Camel1 and Camel2. This way, if Camel1 crashes for example, Camel2 is used for failover.

Camel1 and 2 would do a REST call with the http component for example. Also there would be a request-reply from AppCamel1 up to camel1  or 2.

Is it a valid scenario?

What should I use to interconnect the different Camel instances (AppCamel1 to Camel1 or 2)? (I would like to know if it's possible to avoid another component like a jms server in the middle)

Thank you!

---

Edited following Boday's answer

the REST calls are from Camel1/2. I'd like to interconnect AppCamel1/2 to Camel1/2 and see if I can avoid anything in between. I guess mina is a possibility or even http but in that case a AppCamel1 and AppCamel2 need to know Camel1/2 which is not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also being discussed at the Camel mailing list, where there is also some pointers and suggestions
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/scalable-bus-with-multiple-Camel-instances-tp5606593p5606593.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to load balance HTTP requests to your AppCamel1/2, then you'd need a proxy server in between (apache mod_proxy, perlbal, etc).  To load balance from AppCamel1/2 to Camel1/2, you can use Camel's [load balancer](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) or even JMS request/reply...

From AppCamel1/2 to Camel1/2, it sounds like you are using REST as the interface.  If you need more complex communication between the instances, then I'd use JMS (via [camel-activemq](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html)) for messaging and Hazelcast (via [camel-hazelcast](http://camel.apache.org/hazelcast-component.html)) for distributed caching/locking, etc.

Comment: I added some details in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you use jms to communicate then you do not need a special load balancer. Just use one queue and let both Camel1/2 listen to the queue. Then they will automatically failover and load balance.

Answer (score 1):

I would definetly go for a jms middleware. Activemq is the natural choice (camel is even considered a sub project of activemq). It is trivial to embedd amq along with your canel instances and cluster them. Activemq will then be able to handle both load balancing and failover for you.